# data recovery EFI HD

Tags: data-recovery, partitioning

I sent my PC for repair, but before doing I removed the HD with linux and replaced the one I had purchased it with.

Now I put the HD back on linux but it does not boot.

how can I see the data contained in the HD?

This is the situation of the disk:

[image: partitions]

Comment: It seems that you can install ubuntu over previous. No problem  but encryption case does some difficulties. Simple dont format home disk.

Comment: @Yurij how can I do it ?

Comment: I understand it is a raid:
`ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sda
/dev/sda:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :      1060250 sectors at           40 (type 83)
Partition[1] :      1060284 sectors at      1060296 (type 83)
Partition[2] :    485259386 sectors at      2120584 (type 83)
Partition[3] :       996024 sectors at    487379976 (type 83)`